# handler to generate global variables in tornado

Tags: python, html, tornado, httphandler

I have a top bar in my web application that is common to all the pages. The code for that is in a separate html file, called,base.html that's included in all the other pages(ex. sample.html). Now, I want to load a variable 'notifications' in base.html. I would like to use a separate Handler if possible to generate the notifications for base.html. However, currently, as I understand, I have to call a def to generate it from every page Handler that I write/have written and pass those on. Is there a cleaner way to do this whereby I don't have to change the other page handlers ? Sorry,if this is a stupid question. I'm fairly new to tornado.

```
base.html

// some html 
{{ notifications  }}


sample.html

{% extends base.html %}

// some html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is with a [UIModule](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.UIModule). Create a subclass of `UIModule` which defines a `render` method, pass it in the `ui_modules` dict to the `Application` constructor (`ui_modules=dict(Notifications=NotificationsModule)`), and then you can call it in your templates with `{% module Notifications() %}`